# Redirecting affiliate link: is it okay to add nofollow and noreferrer only to the affiliate link and not the pretty link?

Tags: redirects, nofollow, affiliate

I run a Wordpress website and normally use the plugin Thirsty Affiliates to redirect/cloak my affiliate links with a prettier link.  Wordpress adds the noreferrer and noopener attributes to the pretty link automatically, and then I manually add nofollow to the pretty link.

However, I am experimenting with a content editor (Thrive Architect) which has given me issues with easily adding noopener and noreferrer to my pretty link (I figured out a workaround but it's a pain in the butt).

I was wondering if it is even necessary to add these attributes to the pretty link or whether it needs to be added to the affiliate link instead?

If I leave them off the pretty link, I believe I can get Thirsty Affiliates to add these attributes to the affiliate link on the redirect.

One other question: is noreferrer even worth adding if I do not mind that my affiliate programs know where the traffic is coming from?  or is there some security benefit?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.